# WPF: hide grid rows with GridSplitter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I hide the last two rows after resizing of splitter?
When last two rows are hidden, the webBrowser should fill all the area.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" ResizeDirection="Rows" 
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Width="Auto" Height="5" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Visibility="...">
    </GridSplitter>
    <c:MyControl Grid.Row="2" Visibility="..." />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick fix of this issue:

```
    public class HideableGridSplitter : GridSplitter
    {
        private GridLength height;

        public HideableGridSplitter()
        {
            this.IsVisibleChanged += HideableGridSplitter_IsVisibleChanged;
        }

        void HideableGridSplitter_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid parent = base.Parent as Grid;
            if (parent == null)
                return;
            int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(this);
            if (rowIndex + 1 >= parent.RowDefinitions.Count)
                return;
            var lastRow = parent.RowDefinitions[rowIndex + 1];

            if (this.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                lastRow.Height = height;
            else
            {
                height = lastRow.Height;
                lastRow.Height = new GridLength(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the lastRow has the MinHeight property specified you'll need to add that into the final if/else blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Make a trigger on MyControl.ActualHeight. If 0, set visibility to collapsed

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=ActualHeight}" Value=0>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Problem: webBrowser, after hiding of MyControl and GridSplitter, have the same height as before hiding. WebBrowser doesn't fill the whole area. How can I stretch webBrowser?

Comment: @Rover - Switch Hidden to Collapsed, and I'll update my answer. I forgot Hidden still takes up space in the Layout while Collapsed doesn't.

Comment: @Rachel, hiding works fine before resize with Visibility.Hidden. But after resizing and hiding, height of webBrowser isn't changed. It doesn't depend of MyControl.Visibility (Hidden or Collapsed).

Comment: @Rover Are you setting Horizontal/Vertical alignment in your WebBrowser control to Stretch? And try changing your middle row's height to Auto instead of 5

Comment: @Rachel, it also doesn't work. I've also tried to remove MyControl - same effect.